# How to match values in mongodb array with another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[User Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPLU8.png)

This is a user document in my mongodb, there are many other user documents as well. And have an array of interests like this

```
myInterests['gaming','reading']
```

> This array can be dynamic in the future

I want to write a query in which I can get the list of those users who have these 2 interests or atleast 1 of them, how can I write a query for this?

```
router.get("/", auth, async function (req, res) {
  const { interests: myInterests } = req.user;
  const users = await User.find({
    interests: { $in: [myInterests] },
  }).select({ email: 1, interests: 1 });
  console.log(users);
});
```

I have tried this code but this code is getting me the list of those users only which have these 2 interests. I want to get those users too which have at least 1 of the elements of this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `myInterests` is already an array.
The query should be like this

```
interests: {
      $in: myInterests,
    }
```

instead of

```
interests: {
      $in: [myInterests],
    }
```

Otherwise, it looks for the exact matches using the 2D array.

Working playground => https://mongoplayground.net/p/D2_JwvBUn3k

Comment: @Saad8113, check this out !!